# Numeric Overflow - works when limiting results, not for full query

Tags: sql, select, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm getting an numeric overflow problem in TD.

```
`select 
a1.account_name,
a1.merch_total_units,
sum(a1.merch_total_units) OVER (order by a1.merch_total_units rows 
BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as running_total,
cast (running_total as decimal (8,4))*100/12767296.0000
from sandbox.merchants_total_units a1
group by 1,2,3
order by 3 desc`
```

Interestingly, when filter on running total, the query works. Ex:

```
`select 
a1.account_name,
a1.merch_total_units,
sum(a1.merch_total_units) OVER (order by a1.merch_total_units rows 
BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as running_total,
cast (running_total as decimal (8,4))*100/12767296.0000
from sandbox.merchants_total_units a1
where a1.merch_total_units > 5000
group by 1,2,3
order by 3 desc`
```

I tried changing the #decimal points at every level through the code, doesn't work

Comment: Why is it interesting that when you filter out some data and overflow problem disappears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increase the length of decimal

```
cast (running_total as decimal (18,4))*100/12767296.0000
```